# AngularJS: Referencing 'arguments' of other functions are not allowed

Tags: angularjs, service

I'm just a beginner in AngularJS and I'm a bit stuck.
I have defined a service:

```
'use strict';
var piradsApp = angular.module('piradsApp');
piradsApp.factory('dataService', function(){
  return {
    data: {
    arguments: [
       {
        name: 'T2 Weighted Images',
        entry: [{
           sector: '',
           plane: '',
           laterality: '',
           score: 0,
           comment: ''
        }]
      },
    {...} //it's an array with 4 elements, so didn't copy paste everything
   ]}
  }
});
```

So the service is an array of 4 elements, each containing 2 fields ('name' and 'entry'). 
The 'entry' field contains on his turn 5 fields ('sector', 'plane', 'laterality', 'score' and 'comment')

Now I want to add a new entry to 1 of the 4 elements, I try to do it as follows:

```
var piradsApp = angular.module('piradsApp');
piradsApp.controller('ReportController',
function ReportController($scope, dataService){
   $scope.data = dataService.data;

   $scope.addRow = function(argindex){
     dataService.data.arguments[argindex].entry.push({
        sector: '',
        plane: '',
        laterality: '',
        score: 0,
        comment: ''
   })
 };
});
```

But I get an error which states:
    `Referencing 'arguments' of other function are not allowed`

I looked online, and couldn't find anything about it.
Could anyone tell me why this happens and how to get rid of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi while adding row check whethere r u sending the array index $scope.addRow

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click=addRow(0)> add row</button>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , dataService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = dataService.data;
  console.log($scope.data)

   $scope.addRow = function(argindex){
     dataService.data.arguments[argindex].entry.push({
        sector: 'ghjghjgj',
        plane: 'ghjgjh',
        laterality: 'ghjgjgjgj',
        score: 0,
        comment: ''
   })
   console.log(dataService.data.arguments)
   }
});
app.factory('dataService', function(){
  return {
    data: {
    arguments: [
       {
        name: 'T2 Weighted Images',
        entry: [{
           sector: '',
           plane: '',
           laterality: '',
           score: 0,
           comment: ''
        }]
      }
   ]}
  }
  })
```

[image]

and for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/FvpxG1U18qkW3Ujy5LEn?p=preview